# No-error on opening a java file through eclipse, but produces errors if I just copy the source code

Tags: java, eclipse

For course project, I downloaded a java file and opened a file through Eclipse. At then no error was produced. Now, if I just copy everything from that file to a new file which belongs to package that I made, it produces some error (other than simple package name error). I need to use that file to work on the project. You can get java file from below link.

[Square.java](http://127.0.0.1/Square.java)

at line 21, 'private final Position position;' would cause an error and also

at line 23, 'private final Maze parentMaze;'

All other instances which they use Position or Maze type produces error.

The thing is that above lines do not cause error if I Open the file through eclipse.
Why do errors appear if I just manually copy the source code?

Is there any reason for that? I am new to java that I do not know about some of important rules here..

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are missing the Maze, Position, and MazePathFindingException classes.  Make sure that each of these files is in the correct folder in reference to their package name.  Ex.

MazePathFindingException should be in the folder structure:
"**src_folder**"/edu/illinois/cs/cs242/assignment11/exceptions/

and the other two files should be in the folder structure:
"**src_folder**"/edu/illinois/cs/cs242/assignment11/data/
INCLUDING the file you are getting the errors in.

Otherwise the compiler won't know where to look for these files.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that the reason you didn't see errors is that when you just open a file using file open in eclipse it doesn't parse it for errors because it is not in the context of a project. But when you cut and paste you code into a file that is in a project, Eclipse then applies a full parse and error check because it can now use all the resources applied to that project to validate the code.